# Playwright , How to send parameterised values such as username, password , url from command line?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, cucumber, playwright-typescript

playwright, ts and cucumber are the tools used for my framework

[Playwright website methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omNzl.png)
have tried what says in playwright website too

in element.ts

```
await pageFixture.page.goto(process.env.BASE_URL as string);
await pageFixture.page.locator('input[type=text]').fill(process.env.USER_NAME as string);
await pageFixture.page.locator('input[name=passwd]').fill(process.env.PASSWORD as string);
```

[typescript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALTwp.png)
command line parameters
BASE_URL=https://test.xx.xxx/ USER_NAME=xxxdc.com.au PASSWORD=xcsxxx npm run test

throwing error in windows, vscode

is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- BASE_URL=

could someone help what wrong in the code??

,.....................................................................................................................................